# How can I detect faster a disconnection with Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The code is javascript with node.js 9

I am calling a function that does what Google suggests, ie

```
var connectedRef = database.ref(".info/connected");
connectedRef.on("value", (snap) => {
    if (snap.val() === true) {
        console.log("Have connection");
    } else {
        console.log("Does not have connection");
    }
});
```

Right now, it can take 10 to 20min before seeing the disconnection.

Any clue how I can accelerate it?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
Signed-in to Firebase!
[2020-06-24T18:34:05.537Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Browser went online.
[2020-06-24T18:34:05.664Z]  @firebase/database: event: /.info/connected:value:false
Cloud connection unavailable!
[2020-06-24T18:34:05.711Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Auth token refreshed
[2020-06-24T18:34:07.496Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Making a connection attempt
[2020-06-24T18:34:07.518Z]  @firebase/database: getToken() completed. Creating connection.
[2020-06-24T18:34:07.529Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Connection created
[2020-06-24T18:34:07.619Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://<project>.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.159Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 Websocket connected.
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.201Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Realtime connection established.
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.207Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: connection ready
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.223Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: reportStats {"c":{"sdk.node.6-0-4":1}}
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.230Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: {"r":1,"a":"s","b":{"c":{"sdk.node.6-0-4":1}}}
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.256Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: {"r":2,"a":"auth","b":{"cred":"<credetial>"}}
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.273Z]  @firebase/database: event: /.info/connected:value:true
Cloud connection available!
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.711Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: from server: {"r":1,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.720Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Primary connection is healthy.
[2020-06-24T18:34:08.726Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: from server: {"r":2,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":{<aut_info>},"expires":1593027244}}}
```

.... 19min after.....

```
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.183Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 WebSocket error.  Closing connection.
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.187Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 Network error: wss://<project>.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5: read ETIMEDOUT
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.192Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 WebSocket is closing itself
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.206Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Realtime connection lost.
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.210Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Closing realtime connection.
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.215Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0: Shutting down all connections
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.220Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: data client disconnected
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.225Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Trying to reconnect in 0ms
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.233Z]  @firebase/database: event: /.info/connected:value:false
Cloud connection unavailable!
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.272Z]  @firebase/database: 0: onDisconnectEvents
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.311Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:0:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.320Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Making a connection attempt
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.331Z]  @firebase/database: getToken() completed. Creating connection.
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.335Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Connection created
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.342Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 Websocket connecting to wss://s-usc1c-nss-257.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ls=krlFfSnLVRaMCE7QzqeKNZoPH90e9KmN&ns=<project>
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.384Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 WebSocket error.  Closing connection.
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.387Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 Network error: wss://s-usc1c-nss-257.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ls=krlFfSnLVRaMCE7QzqeKNZoPH90e9KmN&ns=<project>: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN s-usc1c-nss-257.firebaseio.com:443
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.391Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 WebSocket is closing itself
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.398Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.403Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Realtime connection failed.
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.406Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Closing realtime connection.
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.410Z]  @firebase/database: c:0:1: Shutting down all connections
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.414Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: data client disconnected
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.418Z]  @firebase/database: p:0: Trying to reconnect in 833.222046584277ms
[2020-06-24T18:53:41.423Z]  @firebase/database: 0: onDisconnectEvents
```

Comment: That code is using Realtime Database, and not Cloud Firestore. The Firestore documentation may refer to RTDB to implement user presence, but I'd highly recommend not confusing the two products yourself.

Comment: The client should usually detect the disconnect much faster than that. Can you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#enablelogging) and check the log output between when you disconnect, and when the event fires.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I added the log you asked. Do you think is enough to find why it does not trig it quicker?

Comment: Thanks for that log output, really helpful. Do you know when the connection actually dropped in that 19m interval? In logging output, could you for example detect network state (instead of Realtime Database connectivity) to show when that happens? Can you also point/link me to what specific Firebase SDK you are using here?

Comment: I am the one that drops the internet connection and in this case, it is within 10sec or less.  To make sure, I do a ping to confirm it is down.